# Populate value by pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data for locations. I want to concatenate value (having leading spaces) by previous value (no leading spaces).

```
mydata <- read.table(header = T, text = '
                     Locations  Asset   Price
"La Rioja"  "Commercial premises : Rental"  386
"La Rioja"  "Industrial building / warehouse : Rental"  62
" Logroño " "Offices"   103
" Logroño " "Land"  45
" Logroño " "Storage rooms" 8
" Madr "    "Offices"   103
" Madr "    "Land"  45
" Madr "    "Storage rooms" 8
"Las Palmas"    "Offices"   237
"Las Palmas"    "Land"  2277
"Las Palmas"    "Storage rooms" 104
"Madrid"    "Industrial building / warehouse : Rental"  1839
" Pozuelo de Alarcón "  "Offices"   20
')
```

Green highlighted column below is what I am looking for. Red one is my input column.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a different `tidyverse` way without `zoo`.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
   mutate(prefix = case_when(str_sub(Locations, 1, 1) == " " ~ NA_character_,
                             TRUE ~ Locations)) %>%
   fill(prefix, .direction = "down") %>%
   mutate(New_Location = case_when(prefix == Locations ~ prefix,
                                   TRUE ~ paste(prefix, Locations, sep = ","))) %>%
   select(-prefix)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is base R (with some help from `zoo`):

```
tofix <- startsWith(mydata$Locations, " ")
mydata$prefix <- 
  zoo::na.locf(ifelse(tofix, NA, mydata$Locations))
mydata$new_location <-
  ifelse(tofix, paste0(mydata$prefix, ",", mydata$Locations), mydata$Locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dplyr` pipe to achieve this in combination with `na.locf()` from `zoo` package. First identify which elements are main or secondary locations (regex on leading space), then fill the primary locations with the most recent known value and then paste everything together and remove extra columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(Locations_1 = ifelse(grepl("^\\s",Locations), NA, Locations),
         Locations_2 = ifelse(grepl("^\\s",Locations), paste0(",",Locations), ""),
         Locations_1 = na.locf(Locations_1),
         New_Location = paste0(Locations_1, Locations_2)) %>% 
         select(-Locations_1, -Locations_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without additional packages using while loop:

```
counter = 1
counter_concat = 1
d = c()
while (counter <= nrow(mydata)){
  if (trimws(mydata$Locations[counter]) == mydata$Locations[counter]){
    d = c(d,mydata$Locations[counter])
    counter_concat = counter
    counter = counter +1} else{
      d= c(d,paste0(mydata$Locations[counter_concat],',',mydata$Locations[counter]))
            counter = counter +1
    }
}
mydata = cbind(mydata,`New Location` = d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R messy solution:

```
mydata$grp <- ifelse(!grepl("^ ", mydata$Locations),
                     as.character(mydata$Locations), NA_character_)

within(mydata, {
  grp <- na.omit(grp)[cumsum(!(is.na(grp)))]
  Locations <- ifelse(grp != Locations, paste(trimws(Locations, "both"), 
                                  grp, sep = ", "), as.character(Locations))
         rm(grp)})
```